# angular material bottom-sheet drag down to close

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use the angular material bottom sheet(my angular version is 9)

**I want to close the bottom sheet by drag down**

it seems angular-js was supported it: https://material.angularjs.org/1.0.8/demo/bottomSheet

I'm following this link: https://material.angular.io/components/bottom-sheet/examples

**I want to be able to use touch for dragging the bottom sheet to close it for mobile UI.**